# Given a word or set of characters how to only take one part and dispose the rest

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I use Free Pascal where I have to do a task for college course (introduction course to programming).
We are not allowed to use certain words from Free Pascal like `string`, `break`, and some other ones hence my `var` for character is `char`.

Basically I need to take each letter from a word (or set of characters) and do something (in this case add the ASCII value to a number that is increasing each time I add a letter).

I am not able to stop the `while` loop when we find the first dot (`.`). Ideally if the user enters `house.dog.` I need the `while` to do the job only of the letters `h`, `o`, `u`, `s`, and `e` (the ones before the first `.`) and dispose the rest of the text “after the `.`” as will not be used

I have read that there is some internal difference between `Read` and `ReadLn` but could not figure out if that could be affecting the code and the error I get

I tried this code below and do not stop after I enter my word. Keep letting me adding words until I got Runtime error

```
program testingw;
var 
  myText : char;
  myResult : Integer;

begin
  writeLn ('enter your text');
  readLn (myText);

  while myText <> '.' do
  begin
    Read(myText);
    if myText <> '.' then
    begin
      myResult := myResult * 125 + ord(myText);
      WriteLn (myText);
    end;
  end; { while }
end.
```

Comment: Thank you for deleting your 'not-an-answer' answer. The error 201 is a range check error. You may want to [read this](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu4.html) regarding the `integer` type.

Comment: Move your Read statement inside the loop to the bottom of the loop. And as the answer below says, the upper Readln needs to be a Read

Answer (score 1):

First a comment on variable naming: A var named `myText` gives me a mental picture of text of at least several sentences. Doesn't seem to fit well for only a character. `myChar` would be logical choice for a character.

Replace

```
  writeLn ('enter your text');
  readLn (myText);
```

with

```
  writeLn ('enter your text');
  read(myText);    // execution remains here until [Enter],
                   // entered chars are stored in input buffer
                   // myText refers to first char in buffer
```

and the `while` loop with

```
  while myText <> '.' do
  begin
    myResult := myResult * 125 + ord(myText);
    write(myText);
    read(myText);  // Fetch next char in buffer
  end;
```

Note however, that this is tested with Delphi. I can't verify with FP at the moment.

Comment: It works on Free Pascal, but the original code has incorrect Read/Readln statements. The first character will be dropped with the presented logic. Either one Read() or myText has to be initialized and the second Read moved to the bottom of the loop.